# needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `initialize' may cause serious problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I installed a new gem needle in my rails 3.1.

It installed properly but when I start my rails using command `rails server --debugger`

I get the following warnings:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `initialize' may cause serious problems
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining 'object_id' may cause serious problems
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining '__send__' may cause serious problems
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is within the needle gem itself. It does this:

```
public_instance_methods -
[ "instance_eval", "object_id", "__id__", "__send__", "initialize",
  "remove_const", "method_missing", "method", "class", "inspect", "to_s",
  "instance_variables", "block_given?" ]
```

But in Ruby 1.9, the `public_instance_methods` method returns objects of the `Symbol` variety, not `String`. So what happens is effectively this:

```
[:__send__, <and other methods>] - ["__send__", <and other methods>]
=> [:__send__, <and other methods>]
```

When it should be NOT removing those methods in the provided `Array`.

This indicates to me that the library hasn't been updated (or at least tested) for Ruby 1.9. I would recommend finding where the code is for this library, forking it and then applying a patch that converts the array to symbols using something like `map(&:to_sym)` to fix this problem.

But be aware: there may be other cases where these differences between 1.8 and 1.9 are present.

Comment: The force is strong with this one.